# How to sync Indy's server?

Tags: delphi, synchronization, indy

I want to sync Indy's TIdTCPServer's OnExecute, according [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175361/indy-synchronize-servertcpexecute)'s example, but I don't receive the strings. Before I sent the strings directly from the server's execute, the client did receive them, so I'm fairly sure there's not a problem on that side.

Because I need a context to write lines to the buffer, the ServerSync contains an attribute that is to which the context of the execute procedure is assigned.

Server form:

```
unit ServerForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer,
  IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Server: TIdTCPServer;
    memMessages: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses ServerSync;

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Sync : TServerSync;
begin
  Sync := TServerSync.Create(AContext);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Server := TIdTCPServer.Create;
  Server.Bindings.Add.IP:= '0.0.0.0';
  Server.Bindings.Add.Port:= 1990;
  Server.OnExecute := Execute;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  try     
    memMessages.Lines.Add('Activated Server.');
    Server.Active := True;
  except
    on E : Exception do
      ShowMessage( E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message: ' + E.Message );
  end;
end;

end.
```

Server Sync:

```
unit ServerSync;

interface

uses
  IdContext, IdSync;

  type
    TServerSync = class(TIdSync)
    constructor Create( AContext : TIdContext ); overload;
  private
    FContext : TIdContext;
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TServerSync.Create(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  inherited;
  FContext := AContext;
end;

procedure TServerSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  FContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Synced Hello World');
end;

end.
```

Client:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls, IdGlobal, IdIntercept;

type
  TpocForm1 = class(TForm)
    ButtonConnect: TButton;
    ButtonDisconnect: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddLine(text : String);

  private

  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TpocTCPClientThread = class(TThread)
    TCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
    procedure AddLineToMemo;
    procedure Connect;
    procedure Disconnect;
  end;

var
  pocForm1: TpocForm1;

implementation
{$R *.fmx}
Const
  PC_IP = '192.168.32.85';
  PORT = 1990;

var
  thread: TpocTCPClientThread;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client connected with server');
  thread:= TpocTCPClientThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  thread.Terminate;
  thread.WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(thread);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('Client disconnected from server');
end;

procedure TpocForm1.AddLine(text : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(text);
end;


procedure TpocTCPClientThread.Execute();
begin
  Connect;

  while not Terminated do
  begin
    Synchronize(AddLineToMemo);
  end;

  Disconnect;
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.AddLineToMemo;
begin
  pocForm1.AddLine(TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn(IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault()));
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.Connect;
begin
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  TCPClient.Host := PC_IP;
  TCPClient.Port := PORT;
  TCPClient.Connect;
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.Disconnect;
begin
  TCPClient.Disconnect;
  TCPClient.Free;
end;


end.
```

Answer (score 5):

You are making MANY mistakes in this code.

The server code is creating *2* `Bindings` entries when it should only be creating *1* entry.

The server code is never calling `TIdSync.Synchronize()`, which is what queues your overridden `DoSynchronize()` method to be called by the main thread.

The server code is leaking many `TServerSync` objects.  `OnExecute` is a looped event, it is called in a continuous loop for the lifetime of the connection.  You are never calling `Free()` on the `TServerSync` objects that you create on each loop iteration.

The server code is calling `IOHandler.WriteLn()` inside your synchronized `DoSynchronize()` code, and your client code is calling `IOHandler.ReadLn()` inside your synchronized `AddLineToMemo()` code.  They do not belong there!  Socket I/O belongs in your `OnExecute` handlers, not synchronized.  Use synchronizaton to access shared data, update UIs, etc, not to perform socket I/O.

In short, all this code needs to be re-written.  Try something more like this instead:

---

Server:

```
unit ServerForm;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer,
  IdTCPServer, IdContext;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Server: TIdTCPServer;
    memMessages: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  ServerSync;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  Sync : TServerSync;
begin
  Sync := TServerSync.Create(AContext);
  try
    Sync.Synchronize;
    AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Sync.Value);
  finally
    Sync.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Server := TIdTCPServer.Create(Self);
  with Server.Bindings.Add do begin
    IP := '0.0.0.0';
    Port:= 1990;
  end;
  Server.OnExecute := Execute;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Server.Active then Exit;
  try     
    Server.Active := True;
  except
    on E : Exception do
    begin
      ShowMessage( E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message: ' + E.Message );
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
  memMessages.Lines.Add('Activated Server.');
end;

end.
```

```
unit ServerSync;

interface

uses
  IdSync;

type
  TServerSync = class(TIdSync)
  protected
    procedure DoSynchronize; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TServerSync.DoSynchronize;
begin
  // this is called in the context of the main UI thread, do something ...
  Value := 'Synced Hello World';
end;

end.
```

---

Client:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, FMX.Layouts,
  FMX.Memo, FMX.StdCtrls, IdGlobal, IdIntercept;

type
  TpocForm1 = class(TForm)
    ButtonConnect: TButton;
    ButtonDisconnect: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure AddLine(text : String);    
  private
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  pocForm1: TpocForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

const
  PC_IP = '192.168.32.85';
  PORT = 1990;

type
  TpocTCPClientThread = class(TThread)
  private
    TCPClient: TIdTCPClient;
    FLine: string;
    procedure AddLineToMemo(text: string);
    procedure DoAddLineToMemo;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  thread: TpocTCPClientThread = nil;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if thread = nil then
    thread := TpocTCPClientThread.Create(False);
end;

procedure TpocForm1.ButtonDisconnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if thread = nil then Exit;
  thread.Terminate;
  thread.WaitFor;
  FreeAndNil(thread);
end;

procedure TpocForm1.AddLine(text : String);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(text);
end;

constructor TpocTCPClientThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create;
  TCPClient.Host := PC_IP;
  TCPClient.Port := PORT;
end;

destructor TpocTCPClientThread.Destroy;
begin
  TCPClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    TCPClient.Connect;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      AddLineToMemo('Unable to connect to server. ' + E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message: ' + E.Message );
    Exit;
  end;

  try
    try
      AddLineToMemo('Client connected to server');
      TCPClient.IOHandler.DefStringEncoding := IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault;

      while not Terminated do
      begin
        AddLineToMemo(TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLn);
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        AddLineToMemo( E.ClassName + ' error raised, with message: ' + E.Message );
    end;
  finally
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
    AddLineToMemo('Client disconnected from server');
  end;
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.AddLineToMemo(text: string);
begin
  FLine := text;
  Synchronize(DoAddLineToMemo);
end;

procedure TpocTCPClientThread.DoAddLineToMemo;
begin
  pocForm1.AddLine(FLine);
end;

end.
```